# getFocusOwner with a custom class

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield

I need help working getFocusOwner(). I have a Sudoku game that I made in Java and I want to add arrow key navigation to the program. I did some research and found that using the focus system would be the best way (If it's not, please give me a better way and I can research that).

Okay, so for testing purposes, I'm trying to set focus to SetField, a custom class extending JTextField(Custom because I wanted to disable any inputs that weren't numbers). It has been set to focusable. I called requestFocusInWindow() on the SetField in the middle of the grid, and the focus is set to that component. The problem arises when I try and retrieve the component that has focus.

This is what I'm doing to test the getFocusOwner() method:

```
sGrid[40].requestFocusInWindow();

    try{
        System.out.println(this.getFocusOwner().getClass().getSimpleName());
    } catch(NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

No matter what component I try this on, I always get the null pointer exception. I tried it with the JButtons, JLabels, and even on JPanels in my program. The focus is set to the component though. I can see the caret blinking in the intended SetField. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out the problem. For anyone else that's having a problem with this, try using (Window).getMostRecentFocusOwner(). This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of a custom component to only allow numbers, just us a JFormattedTextField.
2. Do you need to even determine which component has focus, why not add a KeyListener, MouseListener?  I am not exactly sure what you doing with the focus but it seems strange.

Comment: All I'm doing is testing the getFocusOwner method by printing out the simple name of the component that it returns. I figured I would have to get which component has focus so I can figure out where the focus will go to after an arrow key is pressed.

I'll look into JFormattedTextField. My current solution doesn't work too well anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add arrow key navigation to the program.

You should be using [Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). Create a basic "ChangeFocusAction". You will need 4 instance of this class that you can map to a KeyStroke.

Assuming you have a array of 81 text fields your Action could be created with an integer value that tells the Action how to change focus. For example:

right = -1
left = 1
up = -9
down = 9

The source of the ActionEvent will contain the text field that has focus. Then you search the arry to find the offset of that text field. Then you add the int value from above to the index and request focus on that component.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking of doing, but I would need to get the component that has focus first right?

Comment: Thats what I said. The ActionEvent has the source component.